# .Net site won't run process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, process, explorer

I have a .Net site that runs a process when a button is clicked. The process opens the file explorer and goes to \\server\printer-name to install the printer's drivers.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"\\" + server + @"\" + printer);
message.InnerText = "Drivers for " + printer + " are downloading now.";
```

When I run this from visual studio the code executes perfectly and the printer's drivers are installed. However when I publish this to a web server and try to run the site there with IIS 6, the process does not start. The odd part is it does not throw an error, and the next line with message.InnerText still executes successfully. I have checked firewall restrictions, permission issues and have looked at IIS settings but have had no luck.

Comment: How do you expect to launch explorer from a non-interactive session?  You can't launch the process on the client's session to my knowledge.

Comment: How come it works when I do it from visual studio though?

Comment: Because it's running in *your* user session.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. Do you have any suggestions to achieve something like this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to install the printer driver on the *web server*? Seems more likely you'd want to install it on the client's machine. Not sure how you'd print from the server or how you'd expect the client to get ahold of the print output.

Comment: @JohnWu yes I need it so when the client clicks the button it installs the printer's drivers on their machine. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: have them download a batch file they can then double-click on to map the print queue.

Comment: You could try redirecting the browser to `@"file:///\\" + server + @"\" + printer`

Comment: @JohnWu when I do that I get a "ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT" from Chrome.

Comment: Due to common security models, a B/S app cannot install anything on a client machine like that. You need to develop a C/S app instead.

Comment: @LexLi I'm sorry, what does B/S and C/S apps stand for? I tried to Google, but it just comes up with App Store results.

Comment: Think he means "browser and server" vs. "client/server." There's only a limited number of things a browser can do, because a browser-based app has to adhere to certain security protocols, and it also has to operate on any operating system. The thing you are attempting to do is specific to Windows and requires elevated permissions, so it is not a good candidate for browser-server functionality.